# Как правильно настроить 3proxy на Raspberry (Raspbian/Debian)?

Tags: linux, сервер, debian, proxy, raspberry-pi

Мало понимаю в таких настройках поэтому обращаюсь за помощью к знатокам :)

Суть:
Хочу поднять мобильный прокси сервер на Raspberry.

Железо:
Есть Raspberry pi3 (Raspbian/Debian) с подклеенным к ней USB модемом, сам Raspberry подключен через пачкорд к WIFI роутеру с домашним интернетом. Для управления Raspberry пользуюсь VNS.

Нашел инструкцию по поднятию прокси с помощью 3proxy: 
[ссылка на инструкцию](https://community.vscale.io/hc/ru/community/posts/115001609005-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-3proxy-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Debian-Ubuntu)

Дошел до пункта создание файла настроек:

```
sudo nano /etc/3proxy/3proxy.cfg
```

Но хватает знаний чтобы правильно заполнить следующие пункты:

1. В примере указаны следующие конфигурации:

   ```
   nserver 8.8.8.8 nserver 77.88.8.8
   ```

но у меня по запросу

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

такие параметры

```
nameserver 10.76.47.115
nameserver 10.76.47.99
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Правильно будет вставить все эти имена?

2. Не до конца понимаю пункт: "Если несколько IP на одном сервере, указываем тот, через который ходить во внешний мир. Иначе эту строку игнорируем external < YOURSERVERIP >"

Правильно понял что нужно указать IP USB модема? Вот так:
external < 10.246.49.433 >

3. В пункте "Тоже самое, только указываем IP, который надо слушать Если проигнорировать, то прокси слушает все адреса на сервере internal < YOURSERVERIP >" какой IP нужно вставить? вообще не понял (извиняюсь за такие вопросы) :)

Comment: И да, опишите задачу. Чего вы хотите добиться в результате?
PS: Вопрос снят. Я вспомнил ваш предыдущий вопрос.. ;-)

Comment: Хочу поднять мобильный прокси для того чтобы его  использовать на стороннем сайте сайте для работы с API инстаграм. Чтобы избежать блокировки от инсты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `/etc/resolv.conf` Можно заменить то что там написано, на

```
1.1.1.1
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

> Не до конца понимаю пункт: "Если несколько IP на одном сервере, указываем тот, через который ходить во внешний мир. Иначе эту строку игнорируем external < YOURSERVERIP >"

Вам ничего не нужно указывать, у вас один внешний айпи, тем более он динамический. А тот что вы указали в примере, с вероятностью 100% айпи вашей сетевой карты.

> В пункте "Тоже самое, только указываем IP, который надо слушать Если проигнорировать, то прокси слушает все адреса на сервере internal < YOURSERVERIP >" какой IP нужно вставить? вообще не понял (извиняюсь за такие вопросы) :)

Тут поставить айпи сетевой карты вашего распберри. Что-б вам было легче ориентироваться, этот айпи может начинаться на `10.x.x.x или 192.168.x.x или на 172.16-31.x.x`

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде стартанул :) Не подскажите как можно его проверить?

Comment: @Дмитрий Если по той инструкции, то порт прокси у вас 3128. Прописываете в настройках браузера http proxy с адресом вашей малинки, а порт 3128 и проверяете. Chrome-like браузеры берут настройки из системы, поэтому лучше поставить расширение [FoxyProxy](https://getfoxyproxy.org/) (для Firefox он тоже есть), ну а там, надеюсь разберётесь. Я им для хождения через TOR пользуюсь, доволен как слон.

Comment: Проверил не работает(  

У меня как я понимаю 2 внешних динамических айпи на малинке 
1. Домашний интернет через роутер
2. USB модем. (если его отключить подключается домашний)

Правильно?

Comment: Не совсем. У вас у малинки статический IP или он все параметры получает по DHCP с вашего домашнего роутера? Покажите вывод команды `ip route` на малинке и, заодно, вывод команды `ip addr`, а, ну и ещё вывод команды `netstat -t4lpn` что-бы точно убедиться в том, что прокси сервер у вас поднят и поднят на том порту про который мы думаем. Выводы команд можно кинуть на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/m5JqNS5p Вроде правильно все сделал :)

У вас у малинки статический IP или он все параметры получает по DHCP с вашего домашнего роутера? Этого я не знаю)